# Validate forms using external services

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to validate an Angular form using an external service but I'm getting a `cannot read property of undefined` error.

I've created a simple form in my component:

```
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  username: ['', [this.validator.username]],
});
```

From there, I'm calling my `username` method:

```
@Injectable()
export class ValidatorService {
  constructor(private auth: AuthService) {}
  username(input: FormControl): {[key: string]: any} {
    return { userInvalid: this.auth.validate(input.value) };
  }
}
```

My ValidatorService, then, calls a method that checks the server if that username exists:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  validate(username: string): boolean {
    return username !== 'demo';
  }
}
```

I'm getting the following error: `Cannot read property 'auth' of undefined`. Any ideas, please?

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-twnoxr?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`username` method is executed like a function not like a method of `ValidationService` so you're loosing context `this`.

`Function.prototype.bind` method should help you:

```
username: ['', [this.validator.username.bind(this.validator)]],
```